# Expanding all nodes in dijit.Tree

Tags: dojo

Is there a good way to expand/close all the expandable nodes in a `dijit.Tree`?

For those looking for an answer, put this in your initializing code:

```
var treeControl = new dijit.Tree({
    model: treeModel,
    expandAll: function() {
        // summary:
        //     Expand all nodes in the tree
        // returns:
        //     Deferred that fires when all nodes have expanded

        var _this = this;

        function expand(node) {
            _this._expandNode(node);

            var childBranches = dojo.filter(node.getChildren() || [], function(node) {
                return node.isExpandable;
            });

            var def = new dojo.Deferred();
            defs = dojo.map(childBranches, expand);
        }
        return expand(this.rootNode);
    }
});
```

At least, that works for me. And you can do the same with `collapseAll()` where you only need to switch `_this._expandNode(node);` with `_this._collapseNode(node);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, autoExpand=true (as an initialization parameter to the Tree).

If you need to expand/collapse dynamically, Tree used to have a method for that, but I took it out.  However, you can copy it from:  http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/changeset/20529.

Comment: Is there a reason it got taken out? And also, it doesn't seem to work on initializing a Tree. We're packaging the whole dojo library, so I don't have direct access on the Tree.js file itself. However, I can create additional methods on it when creating a `new Tree`, but then `_expandNode()` doesn't exist... Any suggestions?

Comment: seems I was getting some problems with the callback function. I just removed that and did a recursive call on `expand()` and the almost identical `collapse()` according to the link you posted, and now it works.

Comment: No particular reason, adding those two methods would bloat the code and require more testing (and I thought we'd still need the expandOnLoad flag too), and it just wasn't clear that anyone wanted to expand/contract dynamically... I guess you do :-)

If you file an enhancement ticket (at http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org) I'll add those methods in.

Answer (score 2):

To collapse all nodes... ( remember *to NOT collapse* the root node when it is not shown( I like to have multiple items shown for my trees ))

```
_collapseAllTreeNodeContainers: function(){ 

     var _tree = _this; 

        function collapse(node) {
   // never collapse root node, otherwise hides whole tree !
   if ( _tree.showRoot == false && node != _tree.rootNode ) {
    _tree._collapseNode(node);
   }

            var childBranches = dojo.filter(node.getChildren() || [], function(node) {
                return node.isExpandable;
            });

            var def = new dojo.Deferred();
            defs = dojo.map(childBranches, collapse);
        }
        return collapse( _tree.rootNode);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use on the `dijit/Tree` instance the following methods:

```
tree.expandAll();
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/Tree#1_10dijit_Tree_expandAll

or

```
tree.collapseAll();
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/Tree#1_10dijit_Tree_collapseAll

Comment: It is part of the API now. No need for monkey patching. Just use these methods.